# ActionBar customizada nao ocupa toda a largura de tela

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbar

Bom, eu estava tentando customizar minha ActionBar, deu certo, mas acontece que ela não preenche toda a largura de tela, é como se ela ficasse sobreposta a antiga, para entender melhor observe a imagem abaixo:

[image: Emulador]

Esta é minha classe .xml da ActionBar customizada:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#bb0000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Tarefas"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btNewTask"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

E este é o meu codigo que seta a ActionBar customizada:

```
public class CustomActionBar {

    static Button btNewTask;

    public static void setCustomActionBarView(ActionBar actionBar, LinearLayout layout, final Context context) {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.LEFT);

        btNewTask = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btNewTask);

        btNewTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "TESTE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        actionBar.setCustomView(layout, params);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Alguem saberia resolver esse problema?

Att. Jeiferson

Comment: por que você não usa uma tooBar ou actionBar?

Comment: @FabianoAraujo mas eu estou usando ActionBar, editei o titulo para melhor compreensao.